# Reaction force response of a single DOF system subjected to a input force $F(t)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, oscillators

I believe the following is the equation of motion for a damped spring-mass single degree of freedom as shown in the schematic.
$$m\ddot{x}+c\dot{x}+kx =F(t)$$

How would one calculate the reaction force $R(t)$ at the ground based on the input force $F(t)$?

For example, if $F(t)$ was a half sine shock load, the reaction force could exceed the input force $F(t)$ due to resonance amplification. I am curious how the response $R(t)$ would be calculated...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \boxed{ R(t) = F(t) - m \ddot{x} = k x + c \dot{x} } \tag{Ans}$$

Just do a free body diagram

[image: fig1]

And you notice the equations of  motion are

$$ m \ddot{x} = F(t) - R(t) $$

from which you extract $R(t)$ when equated with the given equation.

The key insight here is that the spring/damper is just a force member, which means there are equal and opposite forces acting on its ends always. That is if their mass is neglected, as it assumed by the equations of motion presented.

On the other hand, the mass is *not* a force member as $F(t) \neq R(t)$ generally since some of the force goes into accelerating the mass.

Comment: Your first equation would suggest that the reaction force R(t) can never be greater than the input or excitation force F(t)? I am struggling with this because I have an FEM dynamic model where, depending on the half sin impulse duration, the reaction force can be greater or less than the applied force...

Comment: @user9106985 - note that the $m \ddot{x}$ term is both positive and negative at times. There is no reason why $R(t)$ _should_ be less than $F(t)$, it could be either. Only when $m$ is zero you have $R(t)=F(t)$ exactly.